# Require statements missing for imported components in compiled TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

Just started with Angular 2 and I have the weirdest problem. I started with the Angular 2 Quickstart repo from GitHub and added some components with templates.

For instance:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { LayoutComponent } from './layout.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `<layout></layout>`,
})
export class AppComponent  { name = 'Angular'; }
```

The compiled TS (resulting JS file) looks like this:

```
"use strict";
var __decorate = (this && this.__decorate) || function (decorators, target, key, desc) {
    var c = arguments.length, r = c < 3 ? target : desc === null ? desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key) : desc, d;
    if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.decorate === "function") r = Reflect.decorate(decorators, target, key, desc);
    else for (var i = decorators.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (d = decorators[i]) r = (c < 3 ? d(r) : c > 3 ? d(target, key, r) : d(target, key)) || r;
    return c > 3 && r && Object.defineProperty(target, key, r), r;
};
var __metadata = (this && this.__metadata) || function (k, v) {
    if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.metadata === "function") return Reflect.metadata(k, v);
};
var core_1 = require('@angular/core');
var AppComponent = (function () {
    function AppComponent() {
        this.name = 'Angular';
    }
    AppComponent = __decorate([
        core_1.Component({
            selector: 'app',
            template: "<layout></layout>",
        }), 
        __metadata('design:paramtypes', [])
    ], AppComponent);
    return AppComponent;
}());
exports.AppComponent = AppComponent;
//# sourceMappingURL=app.component.js.map
```

As you can see there's require call missing for the LayoutComponent and of course, the Layout component is not found so the layout tag doesn't exist (it results in runtime JS error in browser).

This happens with all of my components with no regards to the path (referencing the component in the same directory or one below/above the current directory).

Why is tsc excluding those imports?

Comment: Try importing without { }. Eg: import LayoutComponent  from './layout.component';

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import { LayoutComponent } from './layout.component';
```

This is simply an import statement with ES6 module syntax and it has nothing to do with Angular or any framework.

> Why is tsc excluding those imports?

Tsc is doing exactly what it should here. It optimized compilation by removing unused symbol.

I believe you're trying to achieve nested components. If `AppComponent` is the root component, you can simply add `LayoutComponent` to `declaration` in `@NgModule` configuration, where the root module is declared.

```
@NgModule({
    ...
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        LayoutComponent
    ]
})
```

Althought, it is preferable to have one root component, so I would encapsulate `LayoutComponent` in a e.g. `LayoutModule` and add them to the root module

```
@NgModule({
    ...
    imports: [
        LayoutModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
    ]
})
```

This is how to make `LayoutComponent` available to be used in `AppComponent`, and pretty much throughout the application if you add the component/module to the root module.

Comment: Neither of the solutions you provided seems reasonable to me. Certainly I won't be adding all my components to the root because that's what imports are for. The other option to invent new module just for the sake of one component (which semantically doesn't belong to or needs a separate module) also doesn't suit me.

Comment: Preferably I'd like a solution where I only change the AppComponent.ts file.

Comment: Again that's not the role of import statements, which is a common mistake. Please refer to the 1st notes of in here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/appmodule.html#


"The import statements at the top of the file and the Angular module's imports array are unrelated and have completely different jobs. The JavaScript import statements give you access to symbols exported by other files so you can reference them within this file. You add import statements to almost every application file. They have nothing to do with Angular and Angular knows nothing about them."

Comment: I'd prefer a solution like you mentioned as well, but AFAIK it's not possible,  anymore. Yes it's used to be possible with `directives` attribute for `@Component` decorator but that's deprecated. More information here:
https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/4a740f2

I have learned it to be a good thing. Component is always used in a context of a module. If `layout` component only makes sense in this application context (the root module), it's clear that the component should be added to `declaration` of the AppModule

Comment: Ok thanks. Yeah I found out that modules are commonly used for grouping/referencing components together and not the import statements within the components itself. I guess it makes more sense that way to cover more advanced scenarios. For simple scenarios it does feel like an overkill but I guess we'll have to accept it.